# Aws Media Convert using php

Tags: php, aws-sdk

I have completed the Media converter using php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   require 'vendor/autoload.php';
   use Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider;
   use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
   use Aws\MediaConvert\MediaConvertClient;
   use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
   use Aws\S3\S3Client;
   $profile = 'default';
   $path = '/path/.aws/credentials';
   $provider = CredentialProvider::ini($profile, $path);
   $provider = CredentialProvider::memoize($provider);
   $client = new Aws\MediaConvert\MediaConvertClient([
       'version' => '2017-08-29',
       'region'  => 'ap-southeast-1',
       'credentials' => $provider
   ]);
    $URI = $client->getEndpoint();
    $info = $client->describeEndpoints();
    $endPoints = $info->get('Endpoints');
    $endPointUrl = $endPoints[0]['Url'];

   $mediaConvertClient = new \Aws\MediaConvert\MediaConvertClient([
       'version' => 'latest',
       'region' => 'ap-southeast-1', 
       'endpoint' => $endPointUrl,
       'credentials' => $provider
   ]);
   $jobSetting = [];

   try {
   $result = $mediaConvertClient -> createJob([
        'Role' => 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/MediaConvertRole' ,
        "Queue"=> "arn:aws:mediaconvert:ap-southeast-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:queues/Default",
        'Settings' => $jobSetting  
    ]); 
    print_r($result);   
   }catch (AwsException $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
       echo "\n";
   }
```

Comment: @gayathiri This was actually very helpful. Thanks for posting!

Comment: What is the format of $jobSetting? I can't seem to get my copied JSON file into the right format for it.